# deactivate nslayoutconstraint declared in viewdidload with function

Tags: swift, function, nslayoutconstraint, viewdidload

My code below declares layout constraints in viewdidload. When the function Selena is called I would like the the constraints to be change to what is in the function selena. When I call the function the object I does not change. It has no effect. I know somehow I have to deactivate the original constraints.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
        i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
        i.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -200),

        i.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
        i.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450),

    ])

}


@objc func selena(){
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
        i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :50),
        i.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -50),

        i.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        i.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450),

    ])

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold a reference to them then use `deactivate`

```
  var oldCons = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
     oldCons = [
        i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
        i.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -200), 
        i.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
        i.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)
     ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(oldCons)

}


@objc func selena(){

    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(oldCons)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
        i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :50),
        i.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -50), 
        i.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        i.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450) 
    ])


}
```

---

height connstraint didn't change you can get it out of the array inside `viewDidLoad`

```
 i.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450).isActive = true
```

and remove it from `selena` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the constraints to variables, and change their constant when you need to change them. Here is the example with your trailing constraint. NO need to change the anchor, only the constant. This is how you do it.

```
var iTrailingConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   iTrailingConstraint = i.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150).isActive = true
}
```

When selena is called, you animate the constant to the desired one. Call layoutIfNeeded() on the controller's view

```
@objc func selena(){
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.iTrailingConstraint?.constant = 50
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  })
}
```